# WSO2 APIM 2.0 Clustering deployment with traffic manager cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

From the document, for traffic manager, except publisher will use HTTPS to communicate with traffic manager, others used thrift and jms. so for thrift & jms related URL:

```
connectionfactory.TopicConnectionFactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientid/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://<Traffic-Manager-host>:5676'
topic.throttleData = throttleDat

<ThrottlingConfigurations>
        <EnableAdvanceThrottling>true</EnableAdvanceThrottling>
        <DataPublisher>
            <Enabled>false</Enabled>
            <Type>Binary</Type>
            <ReceiverUrlGroup>tcp://<Traffic-Manager-host>:9611</ReceiverUrlGroup>
            <AuthUrlGroup>ssl://<Traffic-Manager-host>:9711</AuthUrlGroup>
        ……………………
        </DataPublisher>
        <PolicyDeployer><ServiceURL>https://<Traffic-Manager-host>:9443/services/</ServiceURL>
        ……………………
        </PolicyDeployer>
        ………………
        <JMSConnectionDetails>
            <Enabled>false</Enabled>
            <ServiceURL>tcp://<Traffic-Manager-host>:5672</ServiceURL>
        <JMSConnectionDetails>
        …………………
</ThrottlingConfigurations>
```

Can we config any of the traffic manager host in traffic manager cluster in gateway/publisher/store/key manager?

Comment: Your question is not much clear. Please explain further.

Comment: I mean if i have 2 traffic-manager nodes, how to fill those traffic-manager's non-http(s) URL in gateway/publisher/store/key-manager.

Comment: Or in my POC env.(just one server), no hardware level LB, no DNS level LB, any LB choice for non-http(s) transport ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
<ReceiverUrlGroup>{tcp://127.0.0.1:9612},{tcp://127.0.0.1:9613} </ReceiverUrlGroup>
<AuthUrlGroup>{ssl://127.0.0.1:9712},{ssl://127.0.0.1:9713}</AuthUrlGroup>
```

You can find several patterns of traffic manager deployments [in this blog](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com/search?q=Deploy%20multiple%20traffic%20managers).

Comment: Thx! I will try it.